# Safari call to decodeAudioData errors with null where Chrome works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, web-audio-api

I am using `getUserMedia()` and a `mediaRecorder` to record audio, which I then store as base64 encoded text on a server. Later, it's retrieved from the server, stored client-side, and then, when the user clicks on a play button, it's unencoded and played back. The playback works fine on Chrome, but on Safari `decodeAudioData` throws a `null` err into the catch function.  I have researched this heavily but can't see what could be throwing the exception.

The recording code is:

```
      navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.msGetUserMedia);
      if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        //console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
        navigator.getUserMedia (
          { // constraints - only audio needed for this app
            audio: true
          },
          // Success callback
          function(stream) {
            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = audio.saveRecordedAudio;
          });
       }
```

The playback code is:

```
      const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      const binaryAudioBlob = audio.b64toBlob(b64String);
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
        const bufferArray = reader.result;
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(bufferArray, (buffer) => {
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
          source.start(0);
          console.log('started audio from blob');
        }, function(e){ 
          console.log("Error with decoding audio data" + e);  // e is null
        });
      });
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(binaryAudioBlob);
```

where the `b64toBlob` function is:

```
    b64toBlob: (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) => {
      contentType = contentType || '';
      sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

      const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
      const byteArrays = [];

      for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
          byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
      }

      const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
      return blob;
    }
```

The audio was recorded with Chrome. Is it possible that Chrome is encoding the audio in a format that Safari cannot play? From what I can tell, the default would be WAV so I would think Safari could play that format (vs say Ogg).

Any tips hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default format used by both Chrome and Firefox browsers to record an Audio stream using the MediaRecorder is [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)).

Safari isn't able to read this format, that's why `AudioContext.decodeAudioData()` will fail with such an input.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful information. Is there a way to tell Chrome to use a format that Safari can read in the mediaRecorder, or is there a way to quickly convert to a format Safari _can_ read?

Comment: I just tried passing `mimeType: audio/wav` to `getUserMedia` in the constraints object hoping that would subsequently record in a format that safari could read, but it didn't help.

Comment: AFAIK, only Opus is supported on Chrome's MediaRecorder.

Comment: Seems like the most reliable way to deal with this problem is to convert the opus encoding to mp3 using something like  https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs. But that seems hella complicated for something so simple...

Comment: I think I filed a bug to support more encoding, but I suspect none will be added. I would really like at least wav or flac so I can get exactly the data produced from webaudio, if needed.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, you may probably have a look at this one :https://stackoverflow.com/q/54835984/8620333 maybe you can explain what's happening behind the scene (or if it's a kind of bug)

Answer (score 0):

Safari 11+ plays Opus files with WebAssembly.  You'll need to bypass `decodeAudioData()` and use the Web Audio API directly.  See examples below:

https://fetch-stream-audio.anthum.com/

Comment: Safari still doesn't *support* Opus, your code enables the reading.

Comment: fair enough, I reworded