# Click ignored: Issue with label elements to associate with form controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have associated the label element to form fields using "for" attribute. The issue happens when I show a validation message below the form fields.

For example, in the below demo, form field 1 has a required validation onblur,

1. Select form field 1 by clicking on the label
2. Now **click** on form field 2 label which should set the focus to form field 2, but the focus is not set and ***click is ignored***.

Any ideas what is going on?

```js
$(function () {
 $('#formfield1').blur(function() {
    $('#errorMessage').text('Form field is required').show();
  });
  var counter = 1;
  $('*').on('focus blur', function (e) {
   console.log(counter++ + ' ' + e.type + ' ' + this.id);
  })
  
  $('*').click(function (e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation()
     console.log(counter++ + ' ' + e.target.id + ' clicked ');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
div { margin: 10px; }
label { width: 100px; display: inline-block; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 65px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div>
    <label for="formfield1">Form Field 1</label> <input type="text" id="formfield1" />
  </div>
  <div id="errorMessage" tabindex="1" class="hidden">

  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="formfield2">Form Field 2</label> <input type="text" id="formfield2" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Second one focusses fine for me.

Comment: Side note; `$('*')` should be avoided as a general rule

Comment: @Taplar true, just there to figure out what is going on in general with focus..

Comment: I see the same behavior, and it only happens the first time, before the errorMessage is shown.  Interesting.

Comment: I am able to duplicate your problem, but only occasionally. Most of the time it works and I don't think it has anything to do with your code.

Comment: @ajzbc Did you click on the label?

Comment: I changed the logic to use `focusin focusout` and it doesn't look like things that shouldn't be getting focus are getting them.  It just looks like the focus is not being set on the second one.  I was able to remedy it by putting the `show()` inside a setTimeout with a timeout of like 300ms, but that doesn't explain why it's not focusing by default.

Comment: Problem is the focus is set on mouse up. When you blur you are adding content and that content happens to be placed under the cursor when you clicked. That is causing the "mouse up" to be on the error text and not the label you started the click on.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it for me:

```
$('#formfield1').blur(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () { $('#errorMessage').text('Form field is required').show(); }, 100);
});
```

No idea why, but it works. FYI - I tried it with a timeout of 50, and that did not work.

Comment: Thanks @Ray, this is what I am using today, but `setTimeout` is not ideal in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the error message that appear immediately and push the next field so this one is no more at the place where the click occured. Giving some delay to the text will prevent this:

```js
$(function () {
 $('#formfield1').blur(function() {
    $('#errorMessage').text('Form field is required').delay(1000).show(0);
  });
  
  $('*').on('focus blur', function (e) {
   console.log(e.type + ' ' + this.id);
  })
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
div { margin: 10px; }
label { width: 100px; display: inline-block; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 65px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div>
    <label for="formfield1">Form Field 1</label> <input type="text" id="formfield1" />
  </div>
  <div id="errorMessage" class="hidden">

  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="formfield2">Form Field 2</label> <input type="text" id="formfield2" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Or change the place of the text:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#formfield1').blur(function() {
    $('#errorMessage').text('Form field is required').css('display','inline-block');
  });

  $('*').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + ' ' + this.id);
  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 65px !important;
}

#errorMessage {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="formfield1">Form Field 1</label> <input type="text" id="formfield1" />
    <div id="errorMessage" class="hidden">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="formfield2">Form Field 2</label> <input type="text" id="formfield2" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking to understand why it is happening? I am averting this issue by using `setTimeout` but it is not ideal in some cases for me.. but still the click is ignored and couldn't figure out what is going on. I added tabindex to `#errorMessage` which shows the focus is not set there as well.

Comment: @SelvakumarArumugam the issue is that when you click on the next form it's no more in that place because the error message is being placed there. So the click event is not catched by the field (this is what I understand) ... and yes the click is not catched by the error message too. But if we change the position we can clearly see that the focus is fine which confirm that the placement of the error message is the culprit

Comment: I have added a click handler to see if anything is logged or if ignored. Yes, agreed the placement of the error message is the culprit but the weird part is the click is not registered anywhere. I am trying to find which element is picking up the click.

Comment: @SelvakumarArumugam if you really want to have the accurate explanation, you will need to wait for the Gurus ;) for me the click is catched by 0 element because when you click the error message is not yet on the dom (the click occured before) and then there is probably some race condition where the Dom is updated before applying the click so it won't apply to field also (only speculations from me ..)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the input element position within the DOM being modified when you call the `.show()` function. The `errorMessage` pushes the input down and changes its bounds which focus seems to rely on. If you were to place the `errorMessage` at the bottom so that calling `.show()` does not affect the position of the `formField2` input the focus will work just fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/ykhupeo8/1/